# Issue with combining physics body with model imported using cannon js?

Tags: javascript, three.js, game-development, blender, cannon.js

I have imported a car model as .glb file and i have created a physics body using canon js. When merging this two , position is not becoming correct. Model and physics body is completely another direction. Physics body will always be in x axis and model will be in z axis. I have tried by changing position in blender. But issue has not solved. Sharing code what i have done.

Variables are declared globally. Below code for getting car model

```
const loader = new GLTFLoader();
  loader.load(
    objectURL.href,
    function (gltf) {
      speederMesh = gltf.scene;
      speederMesh.scale.set(1, 1, 1);

      modelBody = speederMesh.getObjectByName("NormalCar1");
      // Get tire meshes from the loaded model
      frontLeftTire = speederMesh.getObjectByName("NormalCar1_FrontLeftWheel");
      frontRightTire = speederMesh.getObjectByName(
        "NormalCar1_FrontRightWheel"
      );
      backRightTire = speederMesh.getObjectByName("NormalCar1_BackRightWheel");
      backLeftTire = speederMesh.getObjectByName("NormalCar1_BackLeftWheel");

      scene.add(speederMesh);
      createCarPhysics(); // Create physics bodies for car parts

    },
    undefined,
    function (error) {
      console.error("Error loading GLB file:", error);
    }
  );
```

Creating physics

```
function createCarPhysics() {
  carBody = new CANNON.Body({
    mass: 50,
    position: new CANNON.Vec3(0, 6, 0),
    shape: new CANNON.Box(new CANNON.Vec3(2, 0.5, 1)),
  });

  vehicle = new CANNON.RigidVehicle({
    chassisBody: carBody,
  });
  const mass = 1;
  const axisWidth = 5;

  const wheelShape = new CANNON.Sphere(0.25);
  const wheelMaterial = new CANNON.Material("wheel");
  const down = new CANNON.Vec3(0, -1, 0);

  wheelBody1 = new CANNON.Body({
    mass,
    material: wheelMaterial,
  });
  wheelBody1.addShape(wheelShape);
  wheelBody1.angularDamping = 0.4;
  vehicle.addWheel({
    body: wheelBody1,
    position: new CANNON.Vec3(-1.2, -0.5, 0.7),
    axis: new CANNON.Vec3(0, 0, 1),
    direction: down,
  });

  wheelBody2 = new CANNON.Body({
    mass,
    material: wheelMaterial,
  });
  wheelBody2.addShape(wheelShape);
  wheelBody2.angularDamping = 0.4;
  vehicle.addWheel({
    body: wheelBody2,
    position: new CANNON.Vec3(-1.2, -0.5, -0.7),
    axis: new CANNON.Vec3(0, 0, 1),
    direction: down,
  });
  wheelBody3 = new CANNON.Body({
    mass,
    material: wheelMaterial,
  });
  wheelBody3.addShape(wheelShape);
  wheelBody3.angularDamping = 0.4;
  vehicle.addWheel({
    body: wheelBody3,
    position: new CANNON.Vec3(1.2, -0.5, 0.7),
    axis: new CANNON.Vec3(0, 0, 1),
    direction: down,
  });
  wheelBody4 = new CANNON.Body({
    mass,
    material: wheelMaterial,
  });
  wheelBody4.addShape(wheelShape);
  wheelBody4.angularDamping = 0.4;
  vehicle.addWheel({
    body: wheelBody4,
    position: new CANNON.Vec3(1.2, -0.5, -0.7),
    axis: new CANNON.Vec3(0, 0, 1),
    direction: down,
  });

  vehicle.addToWorld(world);
}
```

Animate function

```
function animate() {
  cannonDebugger.update();
  controls.update(); 
  world.step(timeStep); // step the stimulation
  if (modelBody && carBody) {
    modelBody.position.copy(carBody.position);
    frontLeftTire.position.copy(wheelBody1.position);
    frontRightTire.position.copy(wheelBody2.position);
    backLeftTire.position.copy(wheelBody3.position);
    backRightTire.position.copy(wheelBody4.position);

    modelBody.quaternion.copy(carBody.quaternion);
    frontLeftTire.quaternion.copy(wheelBody1.quaternion);
    frontRightTire.quaternion.copy(wheelBody2.quaternion);
    backLeftTire.quaternion.copy(wheelBody3.quaternion);
    backRightTire.quaternion.copy(wheelBody4.quaternion);
  } else {
    console.log("cant find model");
  }

  renderer.render(scene, camera);
  requestAnimationFrame(animate);
}
```